# How to expand navigation property after applying filter to its parent?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, odata

I have entities structured in a way that one Account can have multiple locations and each location can have multiple circuits. Basically Account Entity Contains an ICollection of Locations and Location entity contains ICollection of Circuits.

I can use this URL to expand the circuits for each location for some accounts

http://localhost:53153/odata/Account?$filter=AccountId eq 12345&$expand=Locations($expand=Circuits)

Now if I want to filter some locations I can use this endpoint

http://localhost:53153/odata/Account?$filter=AccountId eq 23518&$expand=Locations($filter=LocationId eq 10653 or LocationId eq 140003)

My question is how do I expand the Circuits for the returned two locations in the above endpoint? Just putting ($expand=Circuits) at the end doesnt work.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not familiar with the syntax but this might work:`&$expand=Locations($filter=LocationId eq 10653 or LocationId eq 140003$expand=Circuits)` or `&$expand=Locations($filter=(LocationId eq 10653 or LocationId eq 140003)$expand=Circuits)`

Comment: @StevePy both didnt work :(

Comment: Hmm, ok, been checking up on the doco for OData, another option to try: `?$filter=AccountId eq 23518&$expand=Locations($filter=LocationId eq 10653 or LocationId eq 140003)/Circuits`  Since you can use '$expand=Locations/Circuits' to expand both location and it's circuits. Hard to know what MS devs thought of for nested filtering possibilities. :)

Comment: Thx a lot @StevePy. But this http://localhost:53153/odata/Account?$filter=AccountId eq 23518&$expand=Locations($filter=LocationId eq 10653 or LocationId eq 140003;$expand=Circuits) worked. Even this worked http://localhost:53153/odata/Account?$filter=AccountId eq 23518&$expand=Locations($filter=LocationId eq 10653 or LocationId eq 140003;$expand=Circuits($filter=Id eq 558517))

Answer (score 0):

These worked if in case anyone else needs help

```
http://localhost:53153/odata/Account?$filter=AccountId eq 23518&$expand=Locations($filter=LocationId eq 10653 or LocationId eq 140003;$expand=Circuits)

http://localhost:53153/odata/Account?$filter=AccountId eq 23518&$expand=Locations($filter=LocationId eq 10653 or LocationId eq 140003;$expand=Circuits($filter=Id eq 558517))
```